# Why i am getting this apex_error_code: APEXDEV.IG.NO_PK in my APEX?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

Please help me out on this. I am getting this error in my apex. Is there any problem in my table?

```
Contact your application administrator.

Technical Info (only visible for developers)
is_internal_error: true
apex_error_code: APEXDEV.IG.NO_PK
component.type: APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_REGIONS
component.id: 4680974393042552
component.name: All_Lang_Form
error_backtrace:
----- PL/SQL Call Stack -----
  object      line  object
  handle    number  name
0xb9906910       968  package body APEX_180100.WWV_FLOW_ERROR
0xb9906910      1036  package body APEX_180100.WWV_FLOW_ERROR
0xb9906910      1428  package body APEX_180100.WWV_FLOW_ERROR
0x8e8c5578      5838  package body APEX_180100.WWV_FLOW_INTERACTIVE_GRID
0xbbf33640      2361  package body APEX_180100.WWV_FLOW_REGION_NATIVE
0xbd7e6920      2090  package body APEX_180100.WWV_FLOW_PLUGIN
0x8ea6a168      1408  package body APEX_180100.WWV_FLOW_DISP_PAGE_PLUGS
0x8ea6a168      1892  package body APEX_180100.WWV_FLOW_DISP_PAGE_PLUGS
0x8ea6a168       984  package body APEX_180100.WWV_FLOW_DISP_PAGE_PLUGS
0xb9bd1340      2537  package body APEX_180100.WWV_FLOW_PAGE
0xb9bd1340      2774  package body APEX_180100.WWV_FLOW_PAGE
0xb9338750      4754  package body APEX_180100.WWV_FLOW
0xb92be5d8       173  procedure APEX_180100.F
0xbd94a930         2  anonymous block
```

Actually i added two colume in this perticular table after that i am getting this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to select a primary key for region

choose primary key and set primary key option on

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> is internal error: true

is usually bad news.

Anyway: as you added new columns to a table, try to **synchronize columns**: right click the region (in my example, it is an interactive report) and click yellow-marked option. See if it helps.

[image]

Comment: And it didn't help, I presume? Then set this region's Sever Condition to "Never" (so that it isn't displayed, but - you'll keep it as a backup) and create a new region based on the same table. If it works OK, then remove the "old" (hidden) region.